# C# Razor partial view using an iFrame returns dictionary error "`1" and "`2"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, iframe

I am attempting to load a partial view into an iFrame and receiving the below error. When loading the same partial not inside of a iFrame, there is no issue. Looking for any information as far as what the "`1" and "`2" means in the error message.

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("GetFooPartial", "Foo")"></iframe>
```

```
        public ActionResult GetFooPartial()
        {
            foo<fooOptions> vm = new foo<fooOptions>();
            return PartialView("~/Index.cshtml", vm);
        }
```

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'foo`1[fooOptions]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'foo`2[fooOptions]'
```

Comment: What is the `@model` declaration for that view?  What is the fullly qualified class name (with namespace) for both that declaration and for `foo<T>` in the code shown?  The error is telling you that the types are not the same, do you have information indicating otherwise?

Comment: Can you share the model type of partial view `Index`,it looks like the type of vm is not the correct type.